# Updating a part of buffer in DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11

What is the most efficient way to update a small part of vertex buffer ?

It looks that the best way is to map/update/unmap a temporary buffer and then CopySubresourceRegion from temporary buffer to target buffer. Is it correct ?

Alternatively I can use UpdateSubresource. But as far as I understand - it is slower.

In DirectX12 I can map a region. But what can I do in DirectX11 and earlier ?